# Logstash not able to process / send data to Elasticsearch

Tags: elk

```
[2023-06-16T09:56:09,183][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>8}
[2023-06-16T09:56:09,224][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Config is not compliant with data streams. `data_stream => auto` resolved to `false`
[2023-06-16T09:56:09,253][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>8, :ecs_compatibility=>:v8}
[2023-06-16T09:56:09,263][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Config is not compliant with data streams. `data_stream => auto` resolved to `false`
[2023-06-16T09:56:09,264][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch Output configured with `ecs_compatibility => v8`, which resolved to an UNRELEASED preview of version 8.0.0 of the Elastic Common Schema. Once ECS v8 and an updated release of this plugin are publicly available, you will need to update this plugin to resolve this warning.
[2023-06-16T09:56:09,287][INFO ][logstash.filters.csv     ][main] ECS compatibility is enabled but `target` option was not specified. This may cause fields to be set at the top-level of the event where they are likely to clash with the Elastic Common Schema. It is recommended to set the `target` option to avoid potential schema conflicts (if your data is ECS compliant or non-conflicting, feel free to ignore this message)
```

How do I overcome this issue. I have recently downloaded ELK stack V.8

Comment: These are informational or warnings, they shouldn’t cause anything to not work. Are you sure this is the problem? Also this isn’t about programming so some sister site would probably work better for this problem

Comment: I think this is the problem since I am not able to see any errors other than this that why logstash is not processing the data.. Any idea why? I am using filebeat as input and processing data via csv files.

Comment: To add on my above comment, logstash when sending the data for first time, I can see that index is also not created automatically on elasticsearch